# Cleanest way to include mpld3 plotting into libary while maintaining inline plots in ipython notebooks?

Tags: mpld3

I am writing a more personal library and want to have some class routines , that should work like that:

```
Dog.showImage('MyDog')
```

which should immediately plot an inline figure in my notebooks.
This worked fine as long as I didn't use the plugins, but when I use the mouse position plugin within the libary and the class routine, the only way I found so far is to do:

```
def showImage(arg1)
      f=plt.figure()
      plt.imshow(self.ImageDictionary[arg1])
      plugins.connect(f, plugins.MousePosition(fontsize=14))
      return f
```

getting the returned handle and then call `mpld3.display(f)` within the notebook. Is this the best method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think calling `mpld3.enable_notebook()` is just the thing for you. I usually put this right at the beginning of my notebook, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
%matplotlib inline
mpld3.enable_notebook()
```

With this pattern, you should not return the figure. If you do, it will appear in the notebook twice.  [Here is an example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/da4aea41e6549475a3ca).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, strangely I have mpld3.enable_notebook() at the beginning of my notebook. Still when I generate figures in an external python module with mpld3 , I can't see the figure in the notebook. Regardless of whether I drop mpld3.display() or not. 
The only way that worked for me so far is to explicitely call mpld3.display() in the notebook using the returned handle.

Comment: Does my [example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/da4aea41e6549475a3ca) work for you?  Can you post your notebook that is not working as expected?

Comment: I see the problem, I was commenting out the %matplotlib inline magic.
This for a reason though: I wanted to combine the matplotlib animation features, which are not available in inline plot, as I understand it, with the nice interactive plot of mpld3. 
If you ommit the inline magic, I am nevertheless am able to get mpld3 inline plot with mpld3.display()
You think there is a better way of combining animation with mpld3, e.g. replaying a series of images as an animation.

Thanks